# How do I play a downloaded mp3 file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to play an mp3 file that I downloaded from a database. I can download the mp3 file, but it seems to have missing content as I can't play or open the file. My code to download an mp3 file looks as follows:

```
/*the database stores the file as byte array*/
public ActionResult Download(int rID)
{
    byte[] fileContents = db.Devotions.Where(d=>d.ID == rID).Select(d=>d.BytesStore).SingleOrDefault(); // gets the file
    return File(fileContents, "audio/mpeg3");//returns the file
}
```

How can I play the downloaded mp3 file?

Comment: What client-side measures are you taking? Just sending a file to client doesn't play it to him / her. The client just downloads it.

Comment: the problem is fileContents  {byte[0]} byte array comes back as zero, even though the record contains bytes.why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is returning 0 or the default byte value is because you are using `.SingleOrDefault();`. This will return the first value in the sequence OR the default value, where the default value is 0.

Ensure that the data you are searching for exists in BytesStore before fetching any data.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 required:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="files/download?rID=42" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Works basically everywhere:
[image]